# SSD card locked to launcher after wakening from sleep mode

Tags: launcher, suspend, ssd

Whenever I wake my laptop from sleep mode the SSD card is locked to the launcher. It is not though after booting.

How can I avoid this behaviour?

To avoid misunderstandings: I do want the SSD card to be mounted, I just don't want it to be automatically locked to the launcher.

Version: Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: What is the location of your SSD? Is it in /media/[user] or have you designated a mount location?

Comment: Yes, it is in /media/[user] ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two conventional storage locations are `/media` and `/mnt`. The difference between the two are that `/media` is used for removable and `/mnt` is used for more permanent storage. Removable storage is always automatically mounted in `/media` and is shown on the launcher when mounted. On the other hand, storage mounted on `/mnt` *(or anywhere else)** isn't shown on the launcher, which seems to be the one you want.

For this, you'll have to modify your [fstab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab):

1. Look up the **device address** of your SSD for reference later. An easy way is to go to the Disks app and find your SSD. The address should look like this: `/dev/sda1`. Also find out its **file system type**. For example, it could be ext4, FAT or NTFS.
2. Open a Terminal and type in `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`.
3. Type in the **device** address, **mount point**, **file system type**, **options**, **dump** and **pass** number, all separated by spaces. It should look like this:

   `/dev/sda1 /mnt/[name]    ext4    defaults          0       2`

   Just fix the spaces to match the previous entries just for organization.

   - `/dev/sda1` - example of your device address
   - `/mnt/[name]` - chosen mount point*
   - `ext4` - type of file system type
   - `defaults` - default options
   - `0` - dump sets whether the backup utility dump will backup file system. ["Dump is seldom used and if in doubt use 0."](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#Dump)
   - `2` - tells [fsck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsck) in what order to check the file systems ["In practice, use '1' for your root partition, / and 2 for the
     rest."](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#Pass_.28fsck_order.29)

   **My preferred mount point is `/mnt/archive`. It can actually be anything that isn't already used by the system (e.g. `/data`, `/storage`). If you mount it in `/media`, like `/media/storage`, it will show up on the launcher.*

   The full manual can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab).
4. Save the file.
5. Restart the computer to take effect.

Cheers.